# Protractor OSX bring browser window to front

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am running protractor to test angularjs app. All working fine, but when the browser window is spawned, it is in the background, so I have to cmd-tab to find it, and miss what happens at the start.

Is there any way I can programmatically bring the browser window to the foreground?

Comment: It's a pain in the ass but doesn't seem to be a clean and automated way to do this with just Selenium. It also gives trouble when the web app depends of `:focus` selector. Favorite this question since it would be very helpful to see someone coming up with a solution even if is not selenium based.

Comment: One thing i noticed is that [taking a screenshot programmatically](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-get-screenshots-of-failures) forces the browser focus in Linux. Haven't tested that in OSX though.

Comment: Screenshot is forcing focus in OSX 10.10

Answer (score 6):

You can *trigger an alert and immediately accept it*. Put the following into `onPrepare()`:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    return browser.executeScript("alert('Test');").then(function () {
        return browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
    });
},
```

Or, as @LeoGalucci pointed out, *take a screenshot*:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    return browser.takeScreenshot(); 
},
```

Note that `return` is important here - in this case, `Protractor` would not start executing tests until the promise returned from `onPrepare()` is resolved.

Both options worked for me.